# MVC - Which are controllers and which are views?

Tags: model-view-controller

I am having trouble mapping my site using MVC.

Which are the controllers and views for the following page hierarchy?

Index (Home)

->Players

--->Directory

----->Forwards

----->Defense

--->Profile

----->News

----->Stats

->Teams

--->Directory

------>Division

--->Team Profile

----->News

----->Stats

Using /Players/Profile/Stats as an example, is 'Profile' the controller and 'Stats' the view?  What is 'Players'?  The default (index) page for 'Players' is 'Directory'.  Would 'Players' be a controller too?

Is there a better way to structure this site?

Thanks for your answers.  An existing example would be http://sports.yahoo.com/nhl/players/4351  That's a profile page.  If you click on the other tabs (ex. Split Stats), another view appears.  That's how I want to structure it.  In the yahoo URL, it seems like 'players' is a view and the ID is a parameter of the view.  However, when you click on the other tabs, another view seems to be appended to the URL (ex. http://sports.yahoo.com/nhl/players/4351/splits).  In this case, is 'players' a view and 'splits' a view too?

Answer (score 0):

A `Controller` is a class that is created whose job is to take in data from a get/post and determine which `View` should be returned.  THis is done through controller methods called `Actions`

an example...

MyController --> Has a Action --> Home -->  Home Action Returns --> Home View

Answer (score 0):

You can structure your app however you like. That looks reasonable though.

In your example "/Players/Profile/Stats" Players would be an Area in your MVC application. Profile would be your ProfileController.cs and Stats would be an action within that controller (which has a corresponding view with the same name: Stats.aspx).

Comment: Why wouldn't Player and Team be the areas and then Directory and Profile being controllers with specific actions?

Comment: Gotcha, misread that as "players" and "profiles" and "Stats" would be "areas"

Answer (score 0):

Controllers and Actions don't always map one to one with a navigation map like you presented. However, in your case I would likely created the following Controllers:

```
PlayerController
TeamController
```

The PlayerController would probably have the following actions:

```
GetAll()
GetForwards()
GetDefense()
GetProfile(id)
GetNews(id)
GetStats(id)
```

The TeamController would probably have:

```
GetAll()
GetByDivision(id)
GetProfile(id)
GetNews(id)
GetStats(id)
```

However, since it's difficult to tell just from your navigation map exactly the intention, I can't say for sure.